# I need to find a good BSD Licensed C# SIP Softphone

Tags: c#, sip, telephony

I currently have written an API to a SIP phone system, and would like to integrate a full on SIP softphone into what I already have.

I'm looking to integrate an open source softphone that:

- includes a full featured SIP stack
- is written in C#, or easily integrable into a C# application
- is BSD or similarly licensed
- exposes basic features (dialing, transferring, holding, etc) in a fairly high level way (i.e. it would be easy to just write a UI for it and viola I have a custom softphone)

My goal is to make a proof of concept softphone quickly to be able to demo.  I'd take a completely built softphone that was BSD if I could just rewrite the C# front end.

Thanks and I look forward to the invariably useful feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't an open source C# softphone out there. My own [SIP stack](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/) is C# and open source but it's used for a SIP application server and is missing chunks of functionality needed for a softphone such as an RTP implementation, codecs, audio device interop etc.

The closest thing I know of that may suit your needs is [sipek voip](http://code.google.com/p/sipeksdk/) (I'm pretty sure that used to be called pjsip.net) which is a C# wrapper on the [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) open source SIP and media libraries which are themselves written in C and licensed under GPL; so pjsip doesn't meet your licensing requirement even if you were prepared to use the wrapper library.

The most efficient path for you may be to look around the existing softphones out there and  find one that offers skinning services. IN this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825592/c-net-skinnable-open-source-softphone-sip) which is similar to yours it sounds like the developer is using zoiper. I know counterpath also offer skinning but it's not cheap. Of course if you've got a few months of developer resources sitting idle I'm sure you could build on my or soeon

Answer (score 1):

We are using the [mizu webphone](http://www.mizu-voip.com/Products/WebPhone.aspx). It is not written in C# but it says that it is cross platform so i think that you should be able to use it with C# as well (we are using it from ASP .NET)